# How can I hide the menu o specific pages like sign up and log in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rubygems

I want to know how can I hide the menu on the signup and login page. I got this code.The problem is that the Devise gem does not have a controller where I could hide the menu. So, what is the best way to do this?

application.html.haml

```
- if user_signed_in?
    %nav.navigation
       %ul
         %li
            = link_to "New project", new_place_path
         %li
            = link_to "Profile"
         %li
            = link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete
- else
     %nav.navigation_welcome
      .inner
         %ul
            %li
               = link_to "Login", new_user_session_path
            %li
               = link_to "Sign up", new_user_registration_path
```

For sign up\login I use devise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the devise controllers as described [here](http://devise.plataformatec.com.br/#configuring-controllers). There you can specify a layout that does not include the navbar

Or If you wish to only work on the view layer, you can check the `controller_name`:

```
- if user_signed_in?
    %nav.navigation
       %ul
         %li
            = link_to "New project", new_place_path
         %li
            = link_to "Profile"
         %li
            = link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete
- elsif include_navbar?
     %nav.navigation_welcome
      .inner
         %ul
            %li
               = link_to "Login", new_user_session_path
            %li
               = link_to "Sign up", new_user_registration_path
```

And then in your application helper:

```
def include_navbar?
  controller_name != 'sessions' && controller_name != 'registrations'
end
```